# Email Routing is currently disabled and not routing emails. - but... it is working

Tags: email, routing, mx-record

Im using cloudflare as my domain host and google business email.

We have not had any noticable issues receiving or sending email, however when I logged into cloudflare today I see the error message in the subject line.

What does that mean exactly?  Is this really an issue?

It is telling me that my email routing is mis-configured.

All records that they are telling me to delete are the google entries --- MX records pointing to some variation of aspmx.l.google.com

All records they want me to add are their own cloudflare variation --- MX records point to a variation of   route1.mx.cloudflare.net

I'm not sure if I actually need to do anything here.  Is there REALLY an issue?  Or is cloudflare just upset that I am not using their MX records????

Comment: If you want your mail to go through cloudflare you have to update your MX records. If not, do nothing.